# Start and stop JavaFX background thread with 2 buttons

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx-8

I am trying to make a simple UI to launch a selenium test that has the ability to start a background thread which launches a browser when the Start Button is pressed and stops the thread and closes it when the Stop button is pressed. 
Unfortunately when I click stop after starting it, it does not work. If I let it finish I cannot restart the thread. How would I go about updating this so that I can make it submit a new thread that can be stopped by the stop button.

```
        package application;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;


public class Main extends Application {
    Stage window;
    GridPane grid;
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        /*
         * Set up the stage
         */
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("URL LOADER - V1");
        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        grid.setVgap(8);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        window.setResizable(false);

        /*
         * URL input
         */
        Label URLLabel = new Label("URL");
        GridPane.setConstraints(URLLabel,0,0);
        TextField URLTextField = new TextField();
        URLTextField.setPromptText("https://www.google.com");
        GridPane.setConstraints(URLTextField,1,0);

        /*
         * Create Buttons
         */
        Button buttonStart = new Button("Create");
        GridPane.setConstraints(buttonStart,1,6);
        Button buttonStop = new Button("Stop");
        GridPane.setConstraints(buttonStop,1,8);

        grid.getChildren().addAll(URLLabel,URLTextField, buttonStart, buttonStop);

        /*
         * Create the scene
         */
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 300);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                new VisitPage().Start(this,URLTextField.getText());;
                return null;
            }
        };

        buttonStart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        /*
         * Start Button Clicked
         */
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            new Thread(task).start();

        }

    });

        buttonStop.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            /*
             * Start Button Pressed
             */
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Stop Pressed");

            }
        });

    }

    public class VisitPage {
        private String URL;
        Browser BrowserFactory;
        ThreadLocal<WebDriver> drivers;
        WebDriver Browser;
        public void Start(Task<Void> task, String URL) {
            while (true) {
                if (task.isCancelled())
                {
                        System.out.println("Canceling...");
                        System.out.println("Stop Pressed");
                        Browser.close();
                        Browser.quit();
                        BrowserFactory.CloseDriver(drivers);
                        task.cancel();
                }
                else
                {
            /*
             * Create Browser Factor to make ThreadLocal Browsers
             */
            BrowserFactory = new Browser(1, 1);
            drivers = BrowserFactory.SpawnBrowser();
            /*
             * Grab a Browser
             */
            Browser = BrowserFactory.SpawnDriver(drivers);
            /*
             * Visit and scrape
             */
            Browser.get(URL);
            /*
             * Wait 5 Seconds before closing
             */
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Browser.close();
            Browser.quit();
            BrowserFactory.CloseDriver(drivers);
                 }

             }
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

> As with FutureTask, a Task is a one-shot class and cannot be reused. See Service for a reusable Worker.

So you have to create new task for each run. So I added task as field in Main:

```
Stage window;
GridPane grid;
Task<Void> task;
```

Then create task when start button is clicked:

```
buttonStart.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    /*
     * Start Button Clicked
     */
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        if(task != null) {
            System.out.println("Task already running");
            return;
        }
        task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                new VisitPage().start(this, URLTextField.getText());
                ;
                return null;
            }
        };
        Thread thread = new Thread(task);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();
    }
});
```

On stop button click you have to cancel task:

```
buttonStop.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(task == null) {
                System.out.println("Task not running");
                return;
            }
            System.out.println("Stop Pressed");
            task.cancel();
            task = null;
        }
    });
```

This will do nothing, because it is your responsibility to end task when it is cancelled, and you are not ending your infinite loop.
So your VisitPage should look like this (I skipped testing details, since I do not have them on classpath):

```
public class VisitPage {
    public void start(Task<Void> task, String URL) {
        while (!task.isCancelled()) {
            System.out.println("Running test");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("Test run ended");
        }
        System.out.println("Canceling...");
        System.out.println("Stop Pressed");
        return;
    }
}
```

Some minor points:

Technically `task.cancel()` would end your thread sometimes if you would not catch `InterruptedException` that is thrown if your thread is sleeping.

I am not sure how your code compiled but I had to make some variables final so they can be used in handlers: (never mind, from Java SE 8 local variables can be effectively final)

```
final TextField URLTextField = new TextField();
//...
final  Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>(){
//...
```

I would define created thread as daemon so it will not keep running when you close your UI without stopping tests:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

I also renamed `Start` method to `start`

Comment: Thanks for the answer is there anywhere I can find some good examples and/or tutorials? I am trying to understand how to make it so the button can trigger a new thread when the start button is hit. I updated my code, it works the first time, but will not launch a new thread. I am assuming that is because of task being canceled and not initialized again?

Comment: @Kabone I did not notice yesterday. I updated answer. Since task can be used only once all you have to do is to create new one.